# node.js の execSync の戻り値で stderr を受け取る方法

Tags: node.js

node.js(v4.3.2) の child_process.execSync(command[, options]) の戻り値で stderr を受け取る方法を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

`stderr`が必要でしたら、例えば`spawnSync`を使う方がよいと思います。

以下は`execSync`で無理をする例です。
主に、コマンドに`2>&1`などを付けエラー出力を標準出力にもってくる方法です。
これはシェルの機能ですから、詳しく知りたい場合は`node.js`に関してではなく、シェルやシェルスクリプトに関して調べて下さい。
sh系のシェルを想定しています。

```js
#!/usr/bin/node
"use strict";
var child_process = require("child_process");


console.log("# 標準出力へのリダイレクトによる取得。標準出力と混ざる");
// 最後に true コマンドを実行しているのは必ず成功させる為です
var ls_stdout_and_err = child_process.execSync("ls exist.txt not_exist.txt 2>&1; true");
console.log({ls_stdout_and_err: ls_stdout_and_err.toString()});


console.log("\n# 標準出力へのリダイレクトによる取得。元の標準出力は捨てる");
var ls_stderr = child_process.execSync(
        "ls exist.txt not_exist.txt 2>&1 >/dev/null; true");
console.log({ls_stderr: ls_stderr.toString()});


console.log("\n# 標準出力とエラーを入れ替えて取得");
var ls_stderr = child_process.execSync(
        "ls exist.txt not_exist.txt 3>&1 >&2 2>&3; true");
console.log({ls_stderr: ls_stderr.toString()});


console.log("\n# エラーのキャッチによる取得");
try{
    // 最後に false コマンドを実行しているのは必ず失敗させる為です
    child_process.execSync("ls exist.txt not_exist.txt; false");
}
catch(err){
    console.log({
        ls_stdout: err.stdout.toString(),
        ls_stderr: err.stderr.toString(),
    });
}
```

端末で実行すると例えば以下のようになります。コマンドのエラー出力も混じって表示されている事に注意して下さい。

```
# 標準出力へのリダイレクトによる取得。標準出力と混ざる
{ ls_stdout_and_err: 'ls: cannot access \'not_exist.txt\': No such file or directory\nexist.txt\n' }

# 標準出力へのリダイレクトによる取得。元の標準出力は捨てる
{ ls_stderr: 'ls: cannot access \'not_exist.txt\': No such file or directory\n' }

# 標準出力とエラーを入れ替えて取得
exist.txt
{ ls_stderr: 'ls: cannot access \'not_exist.txt\': No such file or directory\n' }

# エラーのキャッチによる取得
ls: cannot access 'not_exist.txt': No such file or directory
{ ls_stdout: 'exist.txt\n',
  ls_stderr: 'ls: cannot access \'not_exist.txt\': No such file or directory\n' }
```